# Combine SQL Rows and get Value

Tags: sql

I've a dataview with for example the following records:

```
Num Type    Name    
------------------------
17  2       Luke    
22  1       Luke    
22  2       Sandy   
10  1       Sandy   
19  2       Tom 
19  1       Tom
```

How can I combine for example all rows for Sandy and get the total of the **Num** row? But it should get the **Type** as operator (1 = plus, 2 = minus). So for Sandy it would be 10-22 = Total -12

The resulttable should look like this:

```
 Num    Type    Name    
 ------------------------
 4      null    Luke    
 -12    null    Sandy   
 0      null    Tom
```

Is that even possible in pure SQL?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
select name,
       sum(case when type = 1 then num
                when type = 2
                then - num
           end) as num
from t
group by name;
```

I'm leaving out `type` from the query, because it doesn't seem useful.

Comment: thx for the **case when...then**, I totally missed that. I'll accept your answer as the solution

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
       SUM(  CASE WHEN  Type = 1 THEN Num
                  WHEN  Type = 2 THEN -Num
              END
           ) AS Num,
       NULL AS Type, 
       Name,
FROM Dataview
GROUP BY Name;
```